# mysql server crashed -mysqld got signal 6

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql version 5.7.23 and Unable to start mysql server.

`[ERROR] InnoDB: Space id and page no stored in the page, read in are [page id: space=3376699519, page number=1484718080], should be [page id: space=1463, page number=1]
2018-10-04T04:29:19.269829Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=3376699519, page number=1484718080] log sequence number 17294104044079415296 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 189601148.
2018-10-04T04:29:19.269834Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2018-10-04T04:29:19.269872Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed file read of page [page id: space=1463, page number=1]. You may have to recover from a backup.`

Comment: the error say it clearly, your database corrupt or you doesn't copy the log. you may have to recover from a backup

Comment: Hi Rikson,I have fixed this issue by inserting innodb_force_recovery=1 in my.cnf and now mysql started.Thanks

Comment: For readers: don't use MySQL with such configuration enabled. After you recovered your databases, then disable that "force" configuration and restart again in normal mode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check the innodb_force_recovery, set it to 1, and start mysql.
for more details, please read [this](http://blackbird.si/mysql-corrupted-innodb-tables-recovery-step-by-step-guide/)

Comment: and this is the problem with "link answers"...

Comment: The link provided is offline. When answering, add the context and explanations necessary to the question, only then add a link but just for reference.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that Database Data is corrupted. You can try to start mysql instance in recovery mode and you will be able to do backup if you are lucky.
Depends on selected mode tables could be read only

> WARNING: Backup data files before starting service in recovery mode

To start mysql in recovery mode add `--innodb_force_recovery=<mode>` in your mysql startup parameter

mysql supporting values from `0` to `6`
[Mysql recovery docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)

**Example of docker-compose file:**

```
version: '2'
services:
  myservice-mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.17
    volumes:
      - ~/volumes/MyProject/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql/
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=MyProject
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    command: mysqld --innodb_force_recovery=6 --lower_case_table_names=1 --skip-ssl --character_set_server=utf8mb4 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

If mysql started successfully you can use any tool to do dump which you can restore on new not corrupted mysql instance