# ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query for one table only

Tags: mysql, linux

Have been running Mysql on Almalinux without any issues for several months. During a remote query with Workbench an important update of a table failed. After that I have stared to get this error for this one table only.

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query No
> connection. Trying to reconnect...
>
> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
> '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
>
> ERROR:  Can't connect to the server

This error appears for both when accessing the table remotely and when logged on as root via localhost on the server. For remote the error is slightly different though: "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query".

I am getting this only for **this one table** (user_mails). Any other table works fine, I can read, access, update and so on. I can create new tables. It is not a critical table. Just being able to drop would be helpful.

But to give more details. I cannot access, read, alter, rename, dump or drop this one table. I cannot even dump or drop the entire database because of it. I guess is that the table has been likely corrupted during the remote update.

In other words, the socket error message only appears for this table but nothing is out of the ordinary for any other table. The error appears thus different from the proposed solutions I've found on the internet. I wonder if it is even a socket error.

After I've dumped and backed up any other table on the schema, I've tried the following without success:

- Killed all mysql processes.
- Replaced the ibd file of that table from a mirror site.
- Deleted the sock file and restarted the service.
- Edited my.cfn file to use another folder for the sock file, changed from 127.0.0.1 to localhost and other suggestions of edits that I've stomped across.

I've backed up now all other tables. But uninstalling and reinstalling mysql is a last resort that I would like to avoid. Any ideas? Just being able to drop this schema might be sufficient as I can use the backup.

The requested log:

```
2023-10-01T13:50:46.465427Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.34) starting as process 30934
2023-10-01T13:50:46.478844Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-10-01T13:50:46.607584Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-10-01T13:50:46.782680Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-10-01T13:50:46.782712Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-10-01T13:50:46.799516Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.34'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-12/root/usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:1123: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[](size_type) [with _Tp = short unsigned int; _Alloc = std::allocator<short unsigned int>; reference = short unsigned int&; size_type = long unsigned int]: Assertion '__n < this->size()' failed.
2023-10-01T13:52:49Z UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
BuildID[sha1]=0b168807aaca44fa650560191d175e4fd878ff78
Thread pointer: 0x7f3d2c000fc0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f3da4653c10 thread_stack 0x100000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x41) [0x2131091]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x2a2) [0xfee7e2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0xa5) [0xfee995]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x12cf0) [0x7f3dab0cbcf0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x10f) [0x7f3da947aacf]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x127) [0x7f3da944dea5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x2b6b800]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dict_index_add_to_cache_w_vcol(dict_table_t*, dict_index_t*, dict_add_v_col_t const*, unsigned int, bool)+0x1c33) [0x245f773]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x24637f3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd_fill_dict_index(dd::Table const&, TABLE const*, dict_table_t*, THD*)+0x83) [0x2480d13]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dict_table_t* dd_open_table_one<dd::Table>(dd::cache::Dictionary_client*, TABLE const*, char const*, dd::Table const*, THD*, std::deque<char const*, ut::allocator<char const*, ut::detail::allocator_base_pfs<char const*> > >&)+0x10d8) [0x2483d28]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dict_table_t* dd_open_table<dd::Table>(dd::cache::Dictionary_client*, TABLE const*, char const*, dd::Table const*, THD*)+0x97) [0x2485597]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::open(char const*, int, unsigned int, dd::Table const*)+0x1464) [0x218ef34]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_open(TABLE*, char const*, int, int, dd::Table const*)+0x57) [0x10fb957]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(open_table_from_share(THD*, TABLE_SHARE*, char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, TABLE*, bool, dd::Table const*)+0x10e8) [0xf98f48]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(open_table(THD*, Table_ref*, Open_table_context*)+0x1029) [0xde4d39]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(open_tables(THD*, Table_ref**, unsigned int*, unsigned int, Prelocking_strategy*)+0x509) [0xde60e9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(open_tables_for_query(THD*, Table_ref*, unsigned int)+0x91) [0xde74a1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::prepare(THD*)+0x105) [0xed7bc5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0xfc) [0xee381c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0xae7) [0xe7f677]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_sql_command(THD*, Parser_state*)+0x51b) [0xe82e6b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0x2341) [0xe857a1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0x15b) [0xe8631b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0xfde9f8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x2844714]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x81ca) [0x7f3dab0c11ca]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7f3da9465e73]
```

Comment: by problems always look first in the error log

Comment: The log has not been very enlightening for me. All fine then it starts with. "Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware. Can't make sense of it. where mysql died... some open open_table commands. Last one is /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7f3da9465e73].."

Comment: in the lines before must be the cause, post the log please, sometime it is hard to read

Comment: Done, see the edit of my original post. I can't make head and tails of that. The table seems simply corrupted and the scocket error a red herring as all other tables on the same schema are fine.

Comment: the database is corruot yyou must try recovery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52639900/mysql-server-crashed-mysqld-got-signal-6

Comment: Alright, it is not possible to delete the schema forcefully/pyshically? I have nothing to lose at this point save for a potential reinstall. Note it is also only one table affected.

Comment: you can clear the data folder and hiope for the best or remove every thing and start new

Comment: I tried what was suggested with the force recovery. Now the entire schema stopped working and I lost access to all tables within with the same error. Anyhow, many thanks for your help. I will try now the pysical remove and if not resinstall everything.

Comment: Addendum for info: I  ended up puring and reinstalling sql-server, deleting all data files and my.cnf. This was way quicker than trying hour and hours to get the corrupted table to work or drop. Of course, this table as not very important at the end, but as a consquence and having learned from that I do now every 2 hours a backup of my tables. Finally, what caused this error and corruption? I think I had both Dbeaver and Workbench remotely working on the same table which caused some conflict. But that's speculation. From now on I will do my table alterations directly on the server.

Comment: please make always backup for all tables and data regularly, it can always go something wrong